# Is it acceptable to spell fantasy with PH instead of F?

Tags: orthography

I know it used to be spelled that way. I'm just wondering if it's still acceptable.

Comment: It's phine with me.     :-)     ⁠

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ODO:

> [phantasy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/phantasy), n.
>
> Variant spelling of fantasy (restricted to archaic uses or, in modern use, to the fields of psychology and psychiatry).

As seen in an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fantasy%2Cphantasy&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfantasy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfantasy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFantasy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFANTASY%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cphantasy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bphantasy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPhantasy%3B%2Cc0), phantasy is still used, albeit much more rarely.

[image]

So yes, it is still acceptable (you might get a few weird looks though, depending on context).